# Why doesn't \dim_eval:n return appropriate result and behaves weirdly?

Tags: expl3, latex3, dimensions, dimension-expressions

All I needed to do is divide `300pt` by `5mm` to get result either in `pt` or in `mm` units. But I got something else.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
    % following is 60.0ptmm (which is 300/5,
    %  not to mention silly units; ridiculous)
    \dim_eval:n{300pt/5mm}\\

    % following is 14.22636pt (I guess/hope it's correct
    %  conversion of 5mm to pt units)
    \dim_eval:n{5mm}\\

    % following is 21.42857pt (which is 300/14,
    %  not 300/14.22636)
    %   followed by .22636pt (decimal of 14.22636pt;
    %    which is also ridiculous)
    \dim_eval:n{300pt/14.22636pt}
  \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I get correct result in `pt` units (answer that also shows result in `mm` units will be greatly appreciated) when dividing points by millimeters inside `\dim_eval:n`?

Comment: incidentally why do you want the ratio of two lengths to be expressed in pt rather than just as a number?

Comment: is your intention to divide 300mm by 5? (rather than divide by 5pt) ?

Comment: /instrumentation professor hat on/ dividing a length by a length, whatever the units, gives a pure number. Converting a pure number to whatever length has no significance at all... you should multiply it by a length before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\dim_eval:n` uses ε-TeX's `\dimexpr` to perform the calculation, and `\dimexpr` doesn't do floating point arithmetics; it can only divide dimensions by integers. What you get when you do

```
\dim_eval:n{300pt/5mm}
```

is actually

```
\dim_eval:n{300pt/5}mm
```

(thus the “silly units”), and with

```
\dim_eval:n{300pt/14.22636pt}
```

you are actually doing

```
\dim_eval:n{300pt/14}.22636pt
```

which are exactly the output you see.

Use `\fp_to_dim:n` (or `\fp_to_decimal:n` if you don't want the units). With versions of `expl3` older than **May 23, 2019** you need to put the denominator around parentheses to stick the unit to the number. In newer versions multiplication by juxtaposition (*e.g.,* `5mm` or `2pi`) has higher precedence than explicit multiplication and division so that the unit is converted before the division:

```latex
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
    \fp_to_dim:n{300pt/5mm}\\
    % \fp_to_dim:n{300pt/(5mm)}\\
    \fp_to_dim:n{5mm}\\
    % \fp_to_dim:n{300pt/(14.22636pt)}
    \fp_to_dim:n{300pt/14.22636pt}
  \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

It is more natural to express a ratio of two lengths as a number than as a length:

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
  \ExplSyntaxOn

    \fp_eval:n{(300pt)/(5mm)}

   \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```